# Justify Integral resulting the quotient of values of the $\Gamma$ function

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Let for $\alpha\in \mathbb R$ $$\Gamma(\alpha):= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}dx.$$

Recently I bumped into the following: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{u}(1-x)^{v}dx=\frac{\Gamma(u+1)\Gamma(v+1)}{\Gamma(u+v+2)}.$$

The identity seems to be very common, but I wonder how to prove it (in as simple, as possible low-level way).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795619/612798  ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795619/612798

Comment: Also, see: beta function.

Comment: Even the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) has a proof.

Comment: I see the link to the Beta function thank you all. What would be more ethical in this case, to delete the question or to leave it for possible future use?